# Do people still play chess at Washington Square Park?

Tags: otb-chess

Back in the past I know that it used to a pretty popular chess location. Fischer played there when he was young. I think Magnus went their once (a few years ago). I have seen videos with Maurice Ashley and some other famous chess players playing their as well.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if there are still a considerable amount of people that play there in 2016. If I went there could I find a game or would I be waiting for a while?

Comment: Last time I was there (May 2015) - no chess players, but there were some on the Union Square which is close by.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Less and less people are playing at Washington Square. Most people are moving to the Union Square (for business and money).

Check this article: http://thevillager.com/2013/08/08/chess-moves-most-players-are-now-at-union-square/

And also have a look at this great video. A favorite of mine where GM Maurice Ashley beats a trash talking Washington Square player http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/manhattan/washington-square-park-chess-hustler-beaten-grandmaster-article-1.2534837